# MS Access Hidden Tables are still visible through Excel Power Query

Tags: ms-access, powerquery

So I have an Access Frontend that I have distributed to some users, where I have some sensitive tables hidden. To make it even more secure, I have distributed it as .ACCDE, with no ability to unhide the Navigation Pane, no Bypass possible, etc.

I have tested and the tables are successfully hidden from any imports through Access or Excel (regular import through "Data" => "From Access") but they still show up if somebody goes through Power Query ("New Query" => "From MS Access Database").

Is there any way to prevent this?

Thank you

Tables are Hidden:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered encrypting the information in your table?  At least that will make a bit harder for normal users to access the information it contains...

Comment: The Backend tables are encrypted with password but if the user imports the Frontend in Excel using "New Query" => "From MS Access Database", the Hidden tables show up and the data is fully visible, without even prompting for password. Is there any other encrypting mechanism I'm not aware of?